# AndroidPubSub app not connecting to AWS

Tags: android, mqtt, aws-iot

I have configured and installed the AndroidPubSub app.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AndroidPubSub

Unfortunately, it never connects properly. I have verified the region, the endpoint, the Cognito pool id, and the policy name are correct (assuming it is the *Unauth_Role). During the initial testing, the keystore name/password and the certificate id were left with the default values.

The application loads, but when I click Connect, it just keeps trying to reconnect, and it is never successful. There are no errors or response messages in the Android logs. I'm trying to get this working to use as an example for my own application that will be pushing data to an MQTT topic.

Is there other information I need to verify? Am I missing a configuration somewhere? Has anyone gotten this to work recently? I've seen other posts about this elsewhere, but I haven't seen any solutions.

Comment: This seams a little specific to the AndroidPubSub app, have you tried raising an issue against the github project?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the github comments, and they haven't been responding to someone with the same issue. I have seen them answer other questions on here, so I was hoping they would see this and respond. Anyone with AWS IoT MQTT knowledge could help. Unfortunately, not many people have done it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was provided the incorrect Cognito Pool ID. The additional problem I had was that due to the incorrect information, the auto-generated certificate in the keystore was wrong, and since that had already been generated, the app was seeing the existing one and using that. This caused connection problems since it was still trying to use the wrong credentials even after changing them in the variable in the app. The solution was to change the CERTIFICATE_ID field to something new so it would generate a new certificate in the keystore and use that to connect. After doing this, the connection was successful.